# How to connect to remote datanode using hdfs client?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My target is download file from hdfs to local filesystem.
I am using client which connects to remote HDFS NameNode.
    **`hadoop fs -get hdfs://sourceHDFS:8020/path_to_file/file /path_to_save_file`**
And I got an exception.

```
15/03/17 12:18:49 WARN client.ShortCircuitCache: ShortCircuitCache(0x11bbad83): failed to load 1073754800_BP-703742109-127.0.0.1-1398459391664
15/03/17 12:18:49 WARN hdfs.BlockReaderFactory: I/O error constructing remote block reader.
java.io.IOException: Got error for OP_READ_BLOCK, self=/127.0.0.1:57733, remote=bigdatalite.localdomain/127.0.0.1:50010, for file /user/hive/warehouse/b2_olap_hive.db/dim_deal_log/000000_0, for pool BP-703742109-127.0.0.1-1398459391664 block 1073754800_13977
```

My understanding of situation. HDFS client connects to NameNode but NameNode return local DataNode IP (because NameNode and DataNode are located at the same machine). And for remote client `127.0.0.1` is wrong adress of DataNode.

How can I connect to correct datanode? And maybe my understanding is wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind to 127.0.0.1. Make sure that the host name entry in /etc/hosts points to the non loopback interface. Bounce your datanode and namenode.

Comment: See also https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused. But indeed, this should be written in bold in the installation documentation, everyone setting up Hadoop seems to have this issue.